# Iterate through an object and grab the keys to reassign them

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have a small snippet of code. This code will grab an object that has key value pairs. I have another object that is an empty array. I want to iterate over the object and create arrays of each value pair in from the collection and push each array to the empty array object.

What I am currently doing is passing in a collection (empty array) and a function. I want to create another function that wil apply a function to each item in the object. I am able to grab each objects value and empty collection. I need to grab each values key and create an array out it.

```
    var letters = {d: 'dog', e: 'elephant', f: 'flotsam'};
    var iterations = [];

    _.each(letters, function(value, property) {
      iterations.push([value, property]);
    });

    expect(iterations).to.eql([
      ['dog', 'd'],
      ['elephant', 'e'],
      ['flotsam', 'f']
    ]);

// this is the function that accepts a empty collection and callback 
_.each = function(collection, iterator) {
    console.log(Object.keys(collection))
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
      // I want to insert the key where the (i) is located below
      iterator(collection[i],i , collection);
    };
  };
```

I want to grab each key when cycling through the passed collection and insert that key where the (i) is two lines from the bottom of the code snippet below. I tried a few different things but they are not working.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do in the last function. Is `collection` an array or object? It might help if you post your input and final desired output.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to grab the key for each of the letters in the iterator at the bottom of the code snippet in the for loop.

Comment: I think, the OP is trying to implement `_.each` by itself.

Comment: @OmarJandali check [this](https://jsbin.com/kuqazewiwi/3/edit?js,console) .

Comment: I am implimenting and creating an `_.each` function that takes a function and object/array. impliment the function on each item in the array/object

Comment: The collection is the letters object. I want to grab each key, value

Answer (score 0):

Using native `forEach`:

```
_.each = function(collection, iterator) {
    Object.keys(collection).forEach(x => iterator(collection[x], x, collection));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the key value pair you can use the [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the keys of the object for example:

```
const myArray = Object.keys(letters).map((key)=>[letters[key], key])
```

If this is not what you want you can tell me:

Answer (score 0):

isn't only this is enough

`_.map(letters, (v,k)=>[v,k])`

Remember, you can use all the `underscore/lodash` collection functions on object directly with `value/key` pairs.

```js
var letters = {d: 'dog', e: 'elephant', f: 'flotsam'},
    iterations = _.map(letters, (v,k)=>[v,k]);
    
console.log('Iterations: ', iterations);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```